# What is the HTTP return code in case of APIM throttling?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

We published an API through the WSO2 API Manager (currently v2.1 but will soon switch to v2.6) Publisher and throttled it to 100 req/s max (advanced throttling rule). 
What will be the HTTP return code in case of too many requests reaching the maximum allowed per second?

This WSO2 documentation page:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Error+Handling
gives many APIM error codes (including those for throttling limits) but the binding with HTTP code is incomplete and we need to give it to our client.

Is the 900802 APIM error code bound to the HTTP 429 error code as is the 900801?
What about codes between 900803 and 900807?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are the HTTP status codes.

- 900801 - 503
- 900802 - 429
- 900803 - 429
- 900804 - 429
- 900805 - 429
- 900806 - 429
- 900807 - 429

You can identify those codes using [1], [2] and [3].

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/53123b847047564cc342cbbed76c9ccf8a097516/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/throttling/APIThrottleConstants.java#L23

[2] - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/c95361146f7ee15f80f61611a97066545c35664d/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/throttling/ThrottleHandler.java#L620

[3] - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/53123b847047564cc342cbbed76c9ccf8a097516/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/throttling/APIThrottleHandler.java#L267